# Debug Activiti process with Eclipse

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, activiti, business-process-management

Currently to test the processes (the processes all contain Java class type tasks), I connect to the Tomcat machine where the activiti-explorer webapp is installed.
From Eclipse I connect in remote debug to the tomcat machine, and from activiti-explorer I start the process.
This way I can debug the code.

If I **don't want** to use the activiti-explorer webapp, could I debug my code while staying on eclipse?
I was able to run a process from a test class using bees. But I can't debug the code.
Once the process starts, Eclipse doesn't stop on my breakpoints

Thx

Comment: I can't understand how it works. 
With the Activiti API I managed to launch the bpm process (runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey (...)) but I don't understand why Eclipse doesn't stop on my breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't activiti-specific, of course; this is for general debugging of your application:

Launch Tomcat using JPDA mode, like this:

```
${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/catalina.sh jpda start
```

Next, attach your IDE to JPDA port :8000

In Eclipse, this is under `Run` > `Debug Configurations` > `Remote Java Application` > `New`

Choose your Project

Set JPDA connection info (`localhost:8000`)

Connect and then you can set breakpoints in your code, etc. and work normally as if you had launched Tomcat from within Eclipse.

Comment: Maybe I did not say it clear enough.  i would like to know if there is a way to run my processes using activiti api, and debug my java classes with eclipse.  so without using tomcat and without using activiti explorer.  currently i tried to use the "api", connecting to the activiti db.  but when i launch the process, eclipse won't allow me to debug from eclipse.

Comment: The problem is that to perform a debug test on my classes, every time I have to install the new jar in the activiti-explorer lib path, restart the tomcat and establish the remote connection from eclipse. This makes me waste a lot of time. For this I wanted to run the process with the api and use the brakpoints in eclipse, without using tomcat and the webapp.

Comment: It looks like I completely missed the point of the question, and I'm completely ignorant when it comes to activiti. I'll delete the answer as it's not at all helpful.